# R ending a repeat statement after a certain amount of time has elapsed

Tags: r, loops, time

I have a function that potentially can take quite a long time.

I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to stop the function other than something like this:

```
repeat{

  time1 <- Sys.time()
  myfunction(x,y,z,...)
  time2 <- Sys.time()
  if(time2 - time1 > my.time.limit) {
   break
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you really want to define time1 inside the repeat loop in a situation like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an `evalWithTimeout` function in the **R.utils** package.  You can use it like this:

```
require("R.utils")
evalWithTimeout({
  repeat{
    myfunction(x,y,z,...)
  }
}, timeout=my.time.limit, onTimeout="warning")
```

Run `example(evalWithTimeout)` to see other ways to use it.